# When did "fag" become an offensive word?

Tags: offensive-language, language-evolution, sexual-minorities

I'm from Pennsylvania. With the recent threat by the Westboro Baptist Church to [protest the funeral of seven children who perished in a fire](http://www.fox43.com/news/wpmt-westboro-protest-perry-fire-funeral,0,5116994.story), I've been thinking a lot about their infamous catchphrase: "God Hates Fags." Religious debates aside, when did "fag" become an offensive word?

Comment: *Fag* as an English public school junior boy acting as a servant, appears in the [1818 expanded edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zgtaAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA29-PA6&dq=%22fag%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjypPPq5t3VAhWJZlAKHUe6BlgQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22fag%22&f=false) of Samuel Johnson's Dictionary.  It had a different pejorative meaning then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [online etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Fag&searchmode=none) that I use,  "Faggot" came into usage in 1914 and "fag" in 1921. Prior to that definitions included a bundle of sticks for faggot and cigarette for fag.

Comment: So, is "smoking a faggot" a Euphemism for oral sex?

Comment: Fag is still used as a word for cigarette in the UK.

Answer (score 9):

[*Fag*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fag) (with the meaning of *a male homosexual*) has been used since 1920s as short for *faggot*.

As for [*faggot*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=faggot) meaning *male homosexual*, the *Online Etymology Dictionary* has the following notes:

> American English slang, probably from earlier contemptuous term for "woman" (1590s), especially an old and unpleasant one, in reference to *faggot* (n.1) *bundle of sticks*, as something awkward that has to be carried (compare *baggage* "worthless woman," 1590s). It may also be reinforced by Yiddish *faygele* "homosexual", literally "little bird." It also may have roots in British public school slang noun *fag* "a junior who does certain duties for a senior" (1785), with suggestions of *catamite*, from *fag* (verb).

> The explanation that male homosexuals were called *faggots* because they were burned at the stake as punishment is an etymological urban legend. Burning sometimes was a punishment meted out to homosexuals in Christian Europe (on the suggestion of the Biblical fate of Sodom and Gomorrah), but in England, where parliament had made homosexuality a capital offense in 1533, hanging was the method prescribed. Use of *faggot* in connection with public executions had long been obscure English historical trivia by the time the word began to be used for "male homosexual" in 20th century American slang, whereas the contemptuous slang word for "woman" (in common with the other possible sources or influences listed here) was in active use early 20c., by D.H. Lawrence and James Joyce, among others.

Comment: In American English (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541225/on-a-certain-pejorative-in-contemporary-british-english?noredirect=1#comment1567735_541225). In the England I grew up in, "fag" was not used to refer to pejoratively to gay people, it was "bender" or "poofter". Only later (from America) did  "fag" start to be used pejoratively to talk about gay people.